# get stream of a socket object in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, stream

I have a client-server application which communicates over TCP/IP.
I use `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` type object for ascnyronous communication over TCP. Basicly i open connection send/receive data and close connection. And my implementation is based on Socket type objects.
Now i need to use a third-party dll to do something. This dll expects a `System.IO.Stream` type object. So i need to get **Stream** object of my **Socket** object. 
How can i do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Be careful when mixing Socket and Stream - a socket instance is threadsafe - a stream instance is not!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pretty simple really.  The constructor for the NetworkStream class accepts a socket to wrap:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx

```
// NOTE: This demonstrates disposal of the stream when you are 
// done with it- you may not want that behavior.
using (var myStream = new NetworkStream(mySocket)) {
    my3rdPartyObject.Foo(myStream);
}
```

Comment: Just in case the user of that stream will want to call `myStream.Close()`, I recommend to construct the NetworkStream with ownership of the socket: `new NetworkStream(mySocket, true)`. Otherwise you end up wondering why the thread that blocks in a read operation is still blocked after closing the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream ?

Or try looking at the System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx

Comment: Thanks John, The answer of @Chris Shain works. That is what i need.